# Android: Can't set an image once a button is clicked (NullpointerException/IllegalStateException)

Tags: java, android

I'm getting an IllegalStateException and a NullPointerException once the imageview is clicked (App crashes). It is supposed to pass the imageview's image to another imageview. I am also using a fragment for my tabbed activity.

onCreate() and variables

```
private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
private ViewPager mViewPager;
PhotoViewAttacher xAttach;
ImageView tessst;

    @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_whole_details);

    tessst = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fillZoom);
    what = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img1);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

}
```

the Imageview click class

```
    public void clickZoom(View v){
    if(v.getId() == R.id.img1){
        Drawable bb = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.maincolor_btn);
        tessst.setImageDrawable(bb);
        xAttach = new PhotoViewAttacher(tessst);
    }
}
```

the logcat

```
09-06 13:12:45.436 31388-31388/com.example.testapp.coloranalysis E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
               Process: com.example.testapp.coloranalysis, PID: 31388
               java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method for android:onClick
                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:293)
                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4463)
                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18770)
                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5323)
                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
                Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288)
                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4463) 
                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18770) 
                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808) 
                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103) 
                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5323) 
                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824) 
                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640) 
                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
                Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                   at com.example.testapp.coloranalysis.WholeDetails.clickZoom(WholeDetails.java:59)
                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatViewInflater$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(AppCompatViewInflater.java:288) 
                   at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4463) 
                   at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18770) 
                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808) 
                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103) 
                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5323) 
                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824) 
                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640) 
                   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post your stactrace

Comment: added the stacktrace

Answer (score 1):

maybe `tessst` is null.

and thus `R.id.fillZoom` may not in `R.layout.activity_whole_details`

you can move `tessst = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.fillZoom);` to the onCreateView in fragment, of course codes associated with `tessst` also have to move.

Comment: Probably, R.id.fillZoom is in another fragment... What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are adding the onClick listener in XML, with the attribute android: onClick="clickZoom". Now to do that, the `clickZoom` function, must be part of the Activity class, and it sounds like it is not. 
What you have to do, is remove the XML attribute, and set the onClick listener in code, by having your class implement View.OnClickListener interface, and calling `setOnClickListener` on the view.